# Visual Studio 2010 Shell Error - is it Causing this SQL Server error?

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssms, errors, visual-studio-2010, troubleshooting

Visual Studio 2010 Isolated Shell has the infamous "Invalid License Data. Reinstall" error. I have SSMS 2014. I have tried reinstalling several times, I installed Visual Studio 2013 but SSMS doesn't recognize it. When I attempt to open SSMS, it says something like components missing, reinstall. So when I repair it installs the same VS 2010 with same issue.

We have an application with a SQL Server backend database. We have a vendor catalog and then import items to our item database. However, it fails and gives this error code below. So my question is: Could this VS 2010 error be causing this error or is this likely an unrelated issue?

> mscorlib 06/18/2016 8:20:42 PM LoadSettings Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>   at PosBeData.Settings.LoadSettings() PosBeData 06/18/2016 8:20:43 PM Time
>
> Update To: 06/19/2016 12:20 AM 06/18/2016 8:32:47 PM frmImportAdd
>   String or binary data would be truncated. The INSERT statement
>   conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_UPC_Item". The conflict
>   occurred in database "PosBe", table "dbo.Item", column 'Item_ID'. The
>   INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_VendorPartNo_Item". The conflict occurred in database "PosBe",
>   table "dbo.Item", column 'Item_ID'. The statement has been terminated.
>   The statement has been terminated. The statement has been terminated.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   PosBeData.PosBeService.GetAddCatalogItems(dtoV_VendorCatalog[]
>   VendorCatalogItems, String Import_CD, Int32 Category_ID, Int32
>   Sub_Category_ID, Boolean CreateInventory, Boolean CreateCase, String
>   Default_Mfg, UserAuth ua)    at
>   PosBeData.V_VendorCatalogCollection.AddSelectedItems(String Import_CD,
>   Int32 Category_ID, Int32 Sub_Category_ID, Boolean CreateInventory,
>   Boolean CreateCase, String Default_Mfg)    at
>   PosBe.frmVendorCatalog.AddItemsThread() mscorlib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several SQL Server errors in the posted message:

- > String or binary data would be truncated.
- > The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_UPC_Item". The conflict occurred in database "PosBe", table "dbo.Item", column 'Item_ID'.
- > The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_VendorPartNo_Item". The conflict occurred in database "PosBe", table "dbo.Item", column 'Item_ID'.

Those are the result of the server's attempts to execute SQL statements issued by your application. They cannot possibly be caused by problems with Visual Studio or SQL Server Management Studio. SSMS is essentially just another application that, like yours, can connect to the database server. Your being unable to run it cannot possibly affect how SQL queries sent to the server by *your* application are executed.